# How can I add sub-products for a product in ASPDotNetStoreFront?

Tags: asp.net, xml, paypal, shopping-cart, aspdotnetstorefront

I have added a product in ASPDotNetStoreFront. The product is a "diet food plan" with price $xxx. Now I am trying to add some sub-products like "snacks" with price $yyy and this sub-products can be optional. When I click "add to cart" the product with price $xxx + sub-product with $yyy (if selected) should be displayed in the cart page. What is the solution to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this for ASPDotNetStoreFront, you would use a [Kit Product](http://manual.aspdotnetstorefront.com/p-1048-kit-products.aspx).

If it is based off of another product then you want to make sure you use the inventory variant tab and specify the variant id of the product variant to be offered by the kit.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting up something similar to one of these JavaScript examples.

[Example 1](http://ccaples.com/index.php/basic-scripts/examples-i/radio-and-checkboxes)

[Example 2](http://ccaples.com/index.php/basic-scripts/examples-ii/button-w-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons)